# Format great quantities

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter

Hi guys this is my first question and i guess can be easy for you, i want to convert this NSString "42031692.7810" to something like this: $4,2031,692.78, i have the this code:

```
NSString *element = @"42031692.7810";
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [formatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:YES];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    NSNumber *temp = [formatter numberFromString:element];
    NSLog(@"formatter%@",[temp stringValue]);
```

but the output is something like this:

```
2012-04-19 14:43:42.467 HelloWorld[5663:f803] formatter(null)
```

How can i fixed this??? Hope you can help me!!

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the string `@"42031692.7810"`, and you have an `NSNumberFormatter` set to accept things that are styled as currency.  `@"42031692.7810"` is not styled as currency.  Thus it is returning `nil`.

You have to set the number formatter to accept decimal input, turn the string into an `NSNumber`, then set the formatter style to the "Currency" style, and then turn the `NSNumber` back into an `NSString`.

Comment: Yes that really works, i did that you said me, and works, now I'm in doubt with the next problem, I created a NSMutableArray of NSNumbers, but when I iterate the array to print the formatters numbers again the output is NULL

for (i=0,cant=[numArray count];i<cant ; i=i+1) {
NSNumber *elemento = [array1 objectAtIndex:i];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSString *temp = [formatter stringFromNumber:elemento];
NSLog(@"formatter %@",temp);
}

Comment: oh was my fault i was using another array, but your solution really works! thanks a lot